# How to solve "N+1" with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Creating a web application with Ruby on Rails.
In the midst of all this, the N+1 problem arose, I have tried eager_load, but it does not solve the problem.
I would be grateful if you could tell me about the solution.

```rb
# companies_controller.rb

companies = Company.with_include_users
users = User.with_include_company

companies.each do |company|
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    target_user = users.where(id: company.id)
    pp target_user
  end
end
```

```rb
# company.rb

has_many :users
scope :with_include_users, -> {
  eager_load(:users)
}
```

```rb
# user.rb

belongs_to :company
scope :with_include_company, -> {
  joins(:company).eager_load(:company)
}
```

As shown above, we eager_load in the model and outer join. In fact, it has not been resolved.

Comment: Well, you DO make N+1 queries explicitly. Also the inner query makes no sense. Why would you look for a user with an id from a company?

Comment: `users.where(id: company.id)` User and company have the same id?

Comment: @SiimLiiser: well, if it's an auto-incrementing integer sequence, then many things in your app will have id=1

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Thanks.I'm very sorry, but do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: @katahik "N+1 problem" _typically_ refers to "hidden" queries. Where you, say, load a list of users and then print each user's company in a loop (which triggers a company lookup for each user), or something like that. Your snippet is different, you explicitly make these queries. Perhaps, it could be solved by loading users into a hash (id => user) outside of the loop, but without knowing what is it that you want to accomplish, I am really not sure.

Comment: The Bullet gem can be helpful in finding those N+1 queries and then writing better ones to get rid of them. https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve the n+1 problem, you can use the method [includes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) to get your associated objects directly, if you know that you will have to use them in your view.

(untested code bellow)

```rb
# companies_controller.rb

companies = Company.includes(:users)

companies.each do |company|
  company.users.each do |user|
    pp user
  end
end
```